# Why don't we use tubes of vacuum as insulator in houses?

Tags: insulators

If vacuum is a good insulator, why don't we use tubes of it as insulator in houses?

Answer (score 2):

Vacuum is expensive to maintain: think of thermos flasks.

Once  lost, it will be hard and expensive , to be reconstituted.

Whereas insulating materials  are cheap and hardy.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea,  but more expensive than fiberglass.

Comment: also more “breakable” than fibreglass.  Replacing a Thermos bottle is easy, but your walls: not so easy.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero - Good point. Pound a nail to hang a picture...